Does there exist a continuous field of directions in $\mathbb R^3$ tangent to every sphere?
Does there exist a nonconstant continuous map $v: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb S^2$ such that every sphere $S \subset \mathbb R^3$ is tangent to $v(x)$ at some $x \in S$?
Bonus: I also suspect that for topological reasons this is not possible in one dimension lower, for $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb S^1$. Can anyone see a simple proof?

Choose $v$ so that it is not constant, but takes values in some $2$-dimensional plane $H\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. Since every sphere $S$ is tangent to translates of $H$ at exactly two points $x$, it is in particular tangent to $v(x)$ at those two points.
Of course this argument breaks down one dimension below: If we want $v$ to take values in a constant hyperplane there, it would already need to be constant. So I'm not sure what to do about the bonus question.

About the bonus question:
Just take your favorite function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ without critical points, say for example $f(x,y)=x+e^y$ and let $v(x,y)$ be given by the gradient of $f$ normalized and rotated by 90°. Thus $v$ is always orthogonal to the gradient of $f$. Since every sphere is compact, $f$ attains a maximum and a minimum on that sphere. At these points the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to the tangent space of $S$ and for dimension reasons, the tangent space has to be the orthogonal complement of $v$. Hence $v$ has to be in that tangent space.

Oh wow, nice construction…
